# Use Powershell to create access 2007 Queries?

Tags: ms-access, powershell

I have been following [Richard Siddaway's Awesome Series on Powershell+Access2007](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/tags/Access/default.aspx).

Unfortunately it ends before discussing creating/running/modifying access 2007 queries in powershell.  How could this be done?

Comment: What did you have in mind? Is http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2009/11/30/updating-access-data.aspx not suitable?

Comment: Yeah, I can get the update record stuff to work out fine.  I am trying to figure out how to manipulate queries from powershell to an 2007 access db.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you wish to create a view (query) in MS Access?

Comment: I would like to be able to perform CRUD operations on the queries in an access database.  Any query that I read from(execute) I would like to be returned to the powershell session as an object.

Answer (score 0):

The cited series of articles uses a definition of stored procedure that is problematic. [It says](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2010/02/13/access-stored-procedure.aspx):

> An SP is a piece of code that we have
>   defined, and saved in the database".

While this may be correct in a metaphorical sort of way, it's incorrect for Access/Jet/ACE. There is no CODE in the objects in a Jet/ACE database that are referred to by the generic term "procedure. In Access/Jet/ACE, a "procedure" is just a stored QueryDef, as there is no procedural code allowed. I don't know if the OLEDB interface restricts it or not, but my guess is that PROCEDURE means DML query and VIEW means SELECT.

So (and I'm just guessing here -- I'm an Access developer so have no need for doing any of this externally), if you want to create/update a DML QueryDef, you'd use the PROCEDURE keyword and the relevant DML for creating/altering PROCEDUREs. Likewise, with SELECTs, you'd use VIEW (I'm assuming).