# Use powershell to create queries in MS-Access

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I need to automate some data extraction from a Microsoft Access DB.  The DB is provided to me by a third party, and so I do not have control over what is in the DB when it is received.  I need to use Powershell to automate extraction of data from the DB.

Is there any way to use powershell to create a query in the accessDB?  This is, essentially, the essence of the code I am looking for:

```
$l_dbPath = "C:\Path\To\dataBase.accdb"
$l_accessApp = new-object -com access.application
$l_accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($l_dbPath)

$l_query = "SELECT SomeTable.SomeField From SomeTable;"
$l_queryName = "Export_Query"
$l_accessApp.CurrentDB().CreateQueryDef($l_queryName, $l_query)

$l_outputFile = "C:\temp\output.csv"
$e_acExportDelim = 2 #$l_accessApp.Enumerations.AcTextTransferType.acExportDelim #arg.  this does not seem to exist...
$e_HasFieldNamesYes=-1
$l_exportSpec = ""
$l_accessApp.DoCmd.TransferText($e_acExportDelim,$l_exportSpec,$l_queryName,$l_outputFile,$e_HasFieldNamesYes)
$l_accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase()
```

However, the line `$l_accessApp.CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef($l_queryName, $l_query)` fails, because `$l_accessApp.CurrentDB()` returns null, not the current DB.  I can find no way to access `CreateQueryDef` from Powershell.

I have looked at [Programmatically Build Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092523/programmatically-build-access-query), [Create a query dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390420/create-a-query-dynamically-through-code-in-msaccess-2003-vba), [Use Powershell to create access 2007 Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559158/use-powershell-to-create-access-2007-queries), and other posts, but found nothing that works.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
It turns out that the code as I had it above does, in fact, work!  The issue all along was simply that I did not have a machine on which I had both DAO and Access installed.  After testing the separate components (using DAO, and using Access) on different machines, and getting IT support to give me a machine with DAO and Access both actually installed, the above code does in fact work.  (With MS Access installed and loaded, but DAO not installed, `$l_accessApp.CurrentDB()` returns `$null`.  With DAO installed, it returns a DBEngine object, as expected.)

Comment: why do you want to create a query inside the database? just connect to it and do your own extraction.. ie: loop through the rows/columns and create the text file..

Comment: There are other reasons I cannot do as you suggest.  Suffice it to say that what I really need, what I am looking for, is how to access CreateQueryDef from powershell through `$l_accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($l_dbPath)`

Comment: RyanL has provided below the exact answer I was searching for, as well as a few more that may be useful to others with similar issues.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a querydef:

```
$dbe =new-Object -comobject DAO.DBEngine.120
$path="c:\path\to\db.mdb"
$db = $dbe.opendatabase($path)

$l_query = "select table1.* from table1"
$l_queryName="testquery"
$l_outputFile="z:\test.csv"

$db.CreateQueryDef($l_queryName, $l_query)
$db.closedatabase


$l_outputFile = "z:\test.csv"
$e_acExportDelim = 2 
$e_HasFieldNamesYes=-1
$l_exportSpec = ""

$l_accessApp = new-object -com access.application
$l_accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($path)
$l_accessApp.DoCmd.TransferText($e_acExportDelim,$l_exportSpec,$l_queryName,$l_outputFile,$e_HasFieldNamesYes)
            $l_accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase()

$l_accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase()
```

Comment: My current code now, almost exactly.   Thanks.  If only I could figure out why neither `$l_accessApp.CurrentDB` nor `$l_accessApp.DBEngine(0)` work.

Comment: See EDIT to question above: `$l_accessApp.CurrentDB()` does in fact work, when you get DAO _and_ MS Access both properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give something like this a try.  You're extracting information into a CSV without creating a query definition in MS Access.

```
$OpenStatic = 3
$LockOptimistic = 3

$path = "C:\Path\To\dataBase.accdb"

$connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$RecordSet = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset

$connection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$Path" )

$Query = "SELECT SomeTable.SomeField From SomeTable;"

$RecordSet.Open($Query, $Connection, $OpenStatic, $LockOptimistic)

$RecordSet | Out-File  z:\output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach.  Are you married to the idea of actually creating a query def?  My understanding is you're after the results...is this not the case?

```
#db path
$DBPath = "c:\path\to\db.mdb"

#SQL statement to run
$SQL = "select table1.* from table"

#Output file location
$Output = "z:\test.csv"

#Connection
$Con= New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

#Connection string
$con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $path"

#create command and fill dataset
$ConCommand= $Con.CreateCommand()
$ConCommand.CommandText = $SQL
$OAdapt = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $ConCommand
$DS = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$OAdapt.Fill($DS)

#Export
$DS.Tables[0] | export-csv $Output -NoTypeInformation
$Con.Close()
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, just need to change $connection to $con

Answer (score 0):

ExportSpecification is what that needs to be played here in order to get some desired output. This specification has to be created from within Microsoft Access using a wizard.

Using exact paths and specification names, later you have to run above script to get the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use DAO?

```
$OpenStatic = 3
$LockOptimistic = 3


$dbe =new-Object -comobject DAO.DBEngine.120
$db = $dbe.opendatabase("C:\Path\To\dataBase.accdb")

$Query = "SELECT SomeTable.SomeField From SomeTable;"

$rs=$db.openrecordset($query)

$rs| Out-File  z:\output.csv
```

Comment: `$rs| Out-File  z:\output.csv` does not output the records.

Comment: RyanL: if you fix the final line of this answer, it might be more useful to others.  Thanks.